# Understanding table function

Tags: javascript

These lines of code build a table from localstorage, but i have a hard time figuring out the meaning of the two `.foreach` methods, and their meaning for the table. The understanding of the table is for some school homework.

```
//Function creates table for employeeList
function buildTable(data) {
    // creates variable "table"
    let table = document.createElement("table");

        // Create table head and body
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));

        let fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
        let headRow = document.createElement("tr");
        fields.forEach(function (field) {
            let headCell = document.createElement("th");
            headCell.textContent = field;
            headRow.appendChild(headCell);
        });
        table.querySelector("thead").appendChild(headRow);
        data.forEach(function (object) {
            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            fields.forEach(function (field) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.textContent = object[field];
                if (typeof object[field] == "number") {
                    cell.style.textAlign = "left";
                }
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
            table.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(row);
        });
        return table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal table has a structure resembling this:

```
<table>
    <th>
        <td>Heading cell</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td>Normal cell</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The `th` element denotes a heading row and the `tr` one denotes a normal row.

The 2 `foreach` loops deal with adding your data into the table:

- first loop deals with the first row of data `data[0]` which goes into the header because it contains the lables.
- the second loop deals with the rest of the data which goes in normal rows.

`table.querySelector("thead")` and `table.querySelector("tbody")` retrieve the DOM elements that are the parents of your respective rows, generated in each  of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

The first foreach will generate table headers based on the keys of the first object in the `data` array.

The second foreach will render a table row for each of the objects in the `data` array.